# Change tableview row text and image color

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, highlight

I have one tableView. In that I have created custom cell. Now I want to achieve exactly the same effect as shown in image. I tried a lot using selectionStyle and other stuffs, but I am not succeed.

[image]

I want to change the backgroundColor, fontcolor and imagecolor. How can I achieve this? This is the code of my UITableViewCell.

```
    import UIKit

public class BaseTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    class var identifier: String { return String.className(self) }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)


    }

    public override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Gray
    }


    public class func height() -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }

    public func setData(data: Any?, image : String!, alignment: NSTextAlignment!, font: UIColor) {

        self.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Light", size: 12)
        self.textLabel?.textAlignment = alignment
        self.textLabel?.textColor = font

        if let menuText = data as? String {
            self.textLabel?.text = menuText
        }

        self.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: image)
    }

    override public func setHighlighted(highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        if highlighted {


        } else {
            self.alpha = 1.0
        }
    }

    // ignore the default handling
    override public func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {

    }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: when u tap that cell, it should change like that....is this your question

Comment: Yah. It should change like that. @Uday.M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this:

```
override public func setSelected(selected: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected)
    // Do your customization here

    // changing text color
    self.textLabel?.textColor = selected ? UIColor.blueColor() : UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This changes the background color, but I also want to change font color. @bobby

Comment: How can I change the image color?

Comment: **override public func setHighlighted(highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        if highlighted {
         self.alpha = 0.4

        } else {
            self.alpha = 1.0
        }
    }** If I am doing this it is also affected to image.

Comment: "highlited" is performed when the user touch the cell. If you want to persist the effect after the touch, like a section, use my solution, otherwise, do the same with setHighlighted.
To change the image color, you can change the image asset, or change the imageView.tintColor, if your image is rendered as a Template

Comment: try to add this before changing the tintColor : imageView.image = imageView.image?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)

Answer (score -2):

override public func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: true)

```
     self.textLabel?.textColor = selected ? UIColor.blue : UIColor.black
     self.imageView?.tintColor = selected ? UIColor.blue : UIColor.black
```

imageView?.image = imageView?.image!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
     }